# How to configure JupyterLab to look the same when opened?

Tags: configuration, jupyter-lab

I'm developing a small application using JupyterLab that I will distribute around the world. I would like to configure JupyterLab so that when my users download my code, move into the directory, and execute `jupyter-lab`, they will always start with the same view.

For example, I want JupyterLab to open up with the README.md file shown rendered as markdown. I *don't* want Python or Jupyter Notebook files opened (initially).

*Is there a way to configure JupyterLab in this way?**

Comment: I think that workspaces is what you are looking for: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/urls.html#managing-workspaces-cli. I am not sure about the details, but this link to docs should help you to start experimenting.

Comment: @krassowski From what I read of that document, the workspaces is something specific to a machine, but not something that could be distributed with a JupyterLab repository.

Comment: The workspaces are stored as a JSON file which most certainly can be distributed with any repository. In fact many repositories use it for this exact reason to open specific layout of tabs/editors etc.

Comment: @krassowski do you have an example of this somewhere (e.g., Open Source project) that I can examine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jupyterlab-workspace.json` file to specify layout. Here are some examples:

- Dask: [`jupyterlab-workspace.json`](https://github.com/dask/dask-examples/blob/main/binder/jupyterlab-workspace.json) [binder](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/dask/dask-examples/main?urlpath=lab)
- Pangeo: [`jupyterlab-workspace.json`](https://github.com/pangeo-data/pangeo-example-notebooks/blob/master/binder/jupyterlab-workspace.json) [binder](http://binder.pangeo.io/v2/gh/pangeo-data/pangeo-example-notebooks/master)
- [Ian's demo](https://github.com/ian-r-rose/binder-workspace-demo) (possibly outdated)

They work by executing the following command before starting up JupyterLab:

```
jupyter lab workspaces import jupyterlab-workspace.json
```

Do NOT try to create the JSON file manually (do not use them as a reference). Instead create a new workspace, arrange tabs/files as you wish and then use:

```
jupyter lab workspaces export workspace_name > jupyterlab-workspace.json
```

See [the workspaces documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/urls.html#managing-workspaces-cli) for more details. There is also a relevant [topic on discourse](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/configure-initial-layout/1660/2).

For your particular use case I would just create a file with a script that your users would use instead of executing `jupyter-lab`, e.g. a simple two-liner like:

```
jupyter-lab workspaces import jupyterlab-workspace.json
jupyter-lab
```

But if you just want one single file to be shown you may as well just create a wrapper that asks for that file to be opened like:

```
jupyter-lab README.md
```

Please note that there was a bug that meant that above did not work some time ago (it is working well if you have the latest versions of `jupyterlab-server`, `jupyter-server`, `jupyterlab`; while updating remember to update `nbclassic` - if installed - as well).

Comment: Thanks @krassowski This is helpful. I'm particularly intrigued by the last option `jupyter-lab README.md` which is exactly what I'm looking for. The only remaining question is can I execute that and have the markdown shown in the viewer rather than the editor?

Comment: I don't think that is currently possible this way. You would need to use workspaces.