# Is there a way to change the default “tab” to open any notebook that opens when one opens jupyterlab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I am using jupyter lab in an iframe in angular application.
And I want to open notebook insted of launcher tab when Iframe will load.

Comment: Yes, you can define the start up layout (which notebooks to open, how to arrange them, etc) in `workspace.json` file, or you could just use URL paths via `/tree` [as documented](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/urls.html#file-navigation-with-tree). What have you tried so far?

Comment: in config file I tried this c.LabApp.default_url = '/lab/tree/Untitled1.ipynb' but it does not seems to work.
from command line python -m jupyterlab --LabApp.default_url='/lab/tree/Untitled19.ipynb' this seems to work.
I can see workspace foleder but did not find any workspace.json file..
can you explain it in more depth

Comment: @krassowski I need to customize the jupitarlab and open in iframe.
as you mention use /tree where do i have to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure JupyterLab to look the same when opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67536735/how-to-configure-jupyterlab-to-look-the-same-when-opened)

Comment: No I think.....